# Logging All Exceptions in a pyqt4 app

Tags: python, logging, pyqt

What's the best way to log all of the exceptions in a pyqt4 application using the standard python logging api?

I've tried wrapping exec_() in a try, except block, and logging the exceptions from that, but it only logs exceptions from the initialization of the app.

As a temporary solution, I wrapped the most important methods in try, except blocks, but that can't be the only way to do it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to override [`sys.excepthook`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html)

```
def my_excepthook(type, value, tback):
    # log the exception here

    # then call the default handler
    sys.__excepthook__(type, value, tback) 

sys.excepthook = my_excepthook
```