# How to log uncaught exceptions of a QApplication?

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

Where should i use an except block in order to log exceptions of a `QApplication`?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = MainWindow()
MainWindow.show()
try:
    eventLoop = app.exec_()
except Exception, e:
    log.exception(str(e))
```

as the exception won't even reach that block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by overriding the `excepthook`, as seen in the following answer: [Logging All Exceptions in a pyqt4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015047/logging-all-exceptions-in-a-pyqt4-app)

Answer (score 5):

Throwing exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

Overwrite the function bool QApplication::notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent *event) so that it catches all thrown exceptions.

You can implement like this.

```
virtual bool notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event) 
{
     try 
     {
     return QApplication::notify(receiver, event);
     } 
     catch(std::exception& e) 
     {
      qDebug() << "Exception thrown:" << e.what();
     }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work as QApplication.notify catches C++ exceptions, and I need to catch python exceptions.

Comment: How can I do it? I mean, should I translate this code to Python or make a c++ file and make python import it? I'm lost, since this code is C++ and we are talking about python.